# LVDS выход ASUS

Tags: железо

Уже несколько лет существуют материнки ASUS c 40-пиновым LVDS выходом, Asus prime H310T - самая новая, а так же есть модели постарше H110T H81T. Нет ли у кого распиновки, случайно?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Визуально, думаю можно сказать что с 1-го по 8-й сигнальные линии LVDS, выводы 36,37,38 приходят на разьем слева с желтым переключателем на три позиции - питание 12v/19v/отсутствует. Остальное... наверно вызванивать...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я таки нашёл ответ сам. И правда если долго копать сайт интела, можно найти pinout lvds 40 pin. В первой сотни томов по запросу LVDS можно найти. На сайте ASUS почему-то нету.

https://www.intel.com/content/dam/support/us/en/documents/motherboards/desktop/sb/aio_integration_white_paper_v30.pdf

```
40-pin LVDS connector signalsPinSignal 
Pin  Signal name    Pin  Signal name
1   ODD_Lane3_P     21 N/C
2   ODD_Lane3_N     22 EDID_3.3 V
3   ODD_Lane2_P 23 LCD_GND
4   ODD_Lane2_N 24 LCD_GND
5   ODD_Lane1_P 25 LCD_GND
6   ODD_Lane1_N 26 ODD_CLK_P
7   ODD_Lane0_P 27 ODD_CLK_N
8   ODD_Lane0_N 28 BKLT_GND
9   EVEN_Lane3_P    29 BKLT_GND
10  EVEN_Lane3_N    30 BKLT_GND
11  EVEN_Lane2_P    31 EDID_CLK
12  EVEN_Lane2_N    32 BKLT_ENABLE
13  EVEN_Lane1_P    33 BKLT_PWM_DIM
14  EVEN_Lane1_N    34 EVEN_CLK_P
15  EVEN_Lane0_P    35 EVEN_CLK_N
16  EVEN_Lane0_N    36 BKLT_PWR (12 V/19 V)
17  EDID_GND        37 BKLT_PWR (12 V/19 V)
18  LCD_VCC (3.3V/5V/12V) 38 BKLT_PWR (12 V/19 V)
19  LCD_VCC (3.3V/5V/12V) 39 N/C
20  LCD_VCC (3.3V/5V/12V) 40 EDID_DATA
```

Понаблюдав дорожки на материнке - вижу что похоже то что надо. Обратите внимание, разьем **не совпадает** с 40-ножечными разьемами на матрицах LVDS, прийдется таки брать datasheet конкрентной матрицы, проверять совпадение контактов и делать переброс проводов.
И тут же есть разпиновка 8-пинового разьема левее LVDS

```
Table 3: FPD brightness connector signals
Pin Signal name  Description
1 BKLT_EN    Backlight enable
2 BKLT_PWM    Backlight control
3 BKLT_PWR (12 V/19 V)    Backlight inverter power
4 BKLT_PWR (12 V/19 V)    Backlight inverter power
5 BKLT_GND/Brightness_GND   Ground (shared)
6 BKLT_GND/Brightness_GND   Ground (shared)
7 Brightness_Up     Panel brightness increase
8 Brightness_Down   Panel brightness decrease
```

Часто-применяемые распиновки LCD-матриц http://comsystem-tlt.ru/obzori/raspinovka-hodovih-matric-lvds-i-edp

---

UDP удалось подключить, совместив всего лишь 16 пар сигналов (dual-chanel mode провода 3,4,5,6,7,8, 11,12,13,14,15,16, 26,27,34,35) плюс несколько проводов питания (18,19,20, 23,24,25,28,29,30, 36,37,38 ) остальное - в воздухе. EDID и яркость пока что не запаял. В отличии от отзывов про Gigabyte (http://forum.gigabyte.ru/viewtopic.php?t=87695 надеюсь что они свою ошибку исправили, у них есть GA-H310TN-R2 как аналог данной но отзывов пока не нашел), в биосе поставил опцию LVDS Custom, mode: dual chanel, resolution 1920x1080, биос позволяет подключить почти любую (не даю 100% гарантии) матрицу с разрешнием (подчеркиваю) 1920x1080 либо 1600x900. Остальные опции биоса на картинку не влияют (я не заметил изменений в картинке). Я выбрал N173GE-L11 почти на бум (как dual-chanel+40pin+присутствует нужное мне разрешение), и её удалось подсоединить (хотя на сайте асус есть список совместимых с ней матриц, этой нету в списке, рекомендую почитать список тут http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/PRIME-H310T-R2-0/HelpDesk_QVL ). В single mode как не колдовал - картинки нету для 1920x1080 (шлейф на бум попался single mode - никак, допаял второй канал - заработало). Картинку получил.

Ещё особенности. Если при включении не понятно как зажечь LED лампу - нужно на BKLT_EN и BKLT_PWM матрицы подать +3.3 вольт (перемычка с выводом 3).

[image: схема]
Так же можно применить простую схему (выше) на любом MOSFET такой же полярности, использовав его для инверсии выключателя (т.к. найти небольшой нормально-замкнутый микровыключатель очень проблематично - все нормально-разомкнутые, я взял с флоппидиска - он и высокий и миниатюрный, можно тек же с CD-ROM взять "концевик"). Mosfet я взял первый попавшийся с ноутбука. R1 - любой от 0..2КОм, можно перемычку. Я использую для того что бы ограничить ток если выключатель коротнёт на землю. R2 от 10КOм до 1МОм. (Лучше 10К если mosfet незнакомый).  С - 0,1u ... 2u я взял с платы SMD 402-размера с цепи питания чипов, номинал незнаю какой. Сильно большой - будет долго включатся экран (до 10 секунд), сильно маленький (если пикофарады попадуться) - будет дребезг подсветки при пользовании кнопкой. Схема в разрыв линии BKLT_ENABLE, либо на вход 3v3, а выход на BKLT_EN матрицы.

UDP:  7, 8 Brightness_Up Brightness_Down - меняют яркость дисплея просто двумя кнопками на-землю, рывками, порядка 8-ми градаций, 0-я яркость (выключено) есть, близких к нулю яркостей - нету. Наверно для более мягкой яркости нужно применять либо кастомный генератор PWM на микроконтроллере, либо питание ламп запитывать как-то хитро.

P.S. Мы не стоим на месте.
Доступны ASUS prime h410t (к концу лета 2020), а так же аналогичные модели у alsrock gigabyte под h410 и h470 чипсет для intel 10-того поколения. Прошёл всего год. Так что ветка миниатюрных материнок ещё будет жить. Ток потребления с матрицей около 12V 1,5А в режиме загрузка ЦП 0-1% с матрицей.